# Hidden top bar in Xcode 7.1

Tags: swift

I have created an app with 3 pages. When I redirect from one page to another page, the top bar appears with (back) button. I want a hidden top bar.

[image: Screenshot of app with top bar]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply implement this code in the `ViewDidLoad()` of whichever ViewController you'd like to hide your Navigation Controller:

```
navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
```

Comment: Why the `navigationController?.navigationBarHidden == false` argument? Passing `true` will work just fine.

Comment: Oops, added wrong snippet of my own code, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: No problem. I'll edit your original response, if you don't mind.